# find the formula for the following expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$S(n)=\sum _{d=3}^n6^{-d+n}d\,,\qquad n\ge 3$$

I have attempted to take out the $6^n$ out of the sigma as it will be a constant. I'm not sure how to form a sum formula to represent the left over in the sigma.

For example, when $n=5$, we can calculate the sum by $3 \cdot6^2 + 4\cdot 6 + 5 \cdot 6^0.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$S(n)=6^n x\sum _{d=3}^n d\,x^{d-1}=6^n x\left(\sum _{d=3}^n x^{d}\right)'$$

When done, let $x=\frac 16$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the formatting. I don't quite see why we added x here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @skybeach221b. To be able to use derivative